# How to get the input date between start and end date in oracle if input date not available then return max date record

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Please find attached sample data.
Scenario 1: If i provide input date as '21-aug-20' and it satisfies in two aggrement_id then i want the max record on effective_end to be taken. i.e **abcd**.
Scenario 2: If i Provide a date '26-aug-20' and which is not satisfying in any of the rows then it should return max effective end date record. i.e **abce**.

[image: PFA sample data]

Comment: what have you tried? and where does it not work?

Comment: Hi Randy i can get the data for scenario 1 using Analytical functions but i am unable to get the second scenario.

Comment: why is the solution to your first scenario abcd and not abce? 21-aug-20 is between the effective_start and effective_end if you include these dates, but the effective_end of abce is higher than the effective_end of abcd.

Comment: Hi @MarEll consider effective start date for abce is 24-aug-20.its just a copy paste mistake.

Comment: Why do you think you need a stored procedure?

Comment: A_horse_with_no_name I didn't mention anywhere that I need procedure.  I just want a query.

Comment: You tagged the question with PL/SQL which is only used for stored procedures and functions.

Comment: @lobh SQL is the query language, PL/SQL  is the programming language.

Comment: Yes I tagged plsql because I thought my question will reach to more people who has vast knowledge in this topic

Comment: @lobh did my answer work for you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have taken the same data and create a table `demo` out of it. see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=bbe877c0bbab45c7411b25661e40a050)

Could you try with following query,

```
WITH data AS
 (SELECT DATE '2020-08-14' input FROM dual) --input parameter 
SELECT arng_id,st_dt,end_dt
FROM   (SELECT input
              ,demo.*
              ,MAX(end_dt) over(ORDER BY NULL) max_dt --taken max(end_dt) to match in case no result with input parameter
        FROM   demo
              ,data)
WHERE  (input BETWEEN st_dt AND end_dt)  -- matches with input paramater OR
OR     (max_dt BETWEEN end_dt AND input) -- condition when no result with first match 
ORDER  BY end_dt DESC -- order by require to fetch the max record always
FETCH  FIRST 1 ROW ONLY --oracle 12c feature
```

With 11g we can use `ROWNUM`. see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4e6f7908053f8b21f1f6dd7794bc4f24)

> *Note: I have not considered the scenario when the input provided is less than max(end_dt) and no match with any row.*